# Counting the number of occurrences of a combination of values in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm working with data concerning different cases going through a proces consisting of different fases during a certain period in time. Each case has an unique id number. A proces can start in multiple fases and ends in fase "Finished" (except for still ungoing fases). A case can go through a proces multiple times.
The data looks similar to this:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), time = structure(c(17453, 
17458, 17453, 17462, 17727, 17735, 17453, 17484, 17568, 17665, 
17665, 17709, 17727, 17727, 17757, 17819), class = "Date"), old_fase = 
c(NA, "Fase 1", NA, "Fase 1", "Finished", "Fase 1", NA, "Fase 1", "Fase 2A", 
"Finished", "Fase 2A", "Fase 2B", "Finished", "Fase 2B", "Fase 1", 
"Fase 2A"), new_fase = c("Fase 1", "Finished", "Fase 1", "Finished", 
"Fase 1", "Finished", "Fase 1", "Fase 2A", "Finished", "Fase 2A", 
"Fase 2B", "Finished", "Fase 2B", "Fase 1", "Fase 2A", "Fase 2B"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

For my analysis I want to create a new id based on the occurrence of each proces per id. Using group_by and mutate on "id" and "new_fase" creates the following incorrect solution. This happens because of the first occurrence of "Fase 2B" in row 11.

```
df1 %>% 
group_by(id,new_fase) %>% 
mutate(occurrence=row_number())
```

The correct solution should look like this:

```
df1 %>% 
mutate(occurrence = c(rep(1, 4), 2, 2, rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 4)))
```

I tried multiple approaches and read multiple Stackoverflow posts, but I am not able to figure it out correctly. Any help is appreciated, preferably using a tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this temporary solution (thanks to iod's solution on the first example using group_by and mutate).

```
df1 %>% filter(is.na(old_fase) | old_fase == "Finished") %>% # indicates the beginning of a new proces
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(occurrence = row_number()) %>% 
select(id, time, occurrence) %>% 
left_join(df1, ., by = c("id", "time")) %>% 
fill(occurrence)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
df2$occurrence <- with(df2, ave(seq_along(id), id, fase, FUN = seq_along))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, occurrence := seq_len(.N), .(id, fase)]
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! Your solution worked in my earlier example, but unfortunatly my real data was a bit more complex. I've edited my example to represent a sample of my real data. Is there a base R or data.table solution to fix this problem?

Comment: @AdriaanNeringBögel  I find your column names to be changed `with(df1, ave(seq_along(id), id, new_fase, FUN = seq_along))#
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 3`  Other than that is is working fine

Comment: I also changed the example contents to better represent my actual data. Your solution worked on the previous example, which represented 99% of my data. My prefered output is shown in the third code block. I've posted an answer with my current not so fancy solution to achieve this output.

Answer (score 2):

```
df3<- df1 %>% 
  group_by(id,fase) %>% 
  mutate(occurrence=row_number())

df3
# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   id, fase [9]
      id fase  time       occurrence
   <dbl> <chr> <date>          <int>
 1     1 a     2018-01-01          1
 2     1 b     2018-01-02          1
 3     1 c     2018-01-03          1
 4     2 a     2018-01-01          1
 5     2 b     2018-01-02          1
 6     2 c     2018-01-03          1
 7     2 a     2018-01-04          2
 8     2 b     2018-01-05          2
 9     2 c     2018-01-06          2
10     2 a     2018-01-07          3
11     2 b     2018-01-08          3
12     2 c     2018-01-09          3
13     3 a     2018-01-01          1
14     3 b     2018-01-02          1
15     3 c     2018-01-03          1
16     3 a     2018-01-04          2
17     3 b     2018-01-05          2
18     3 c     2018-01-06          2

all(df2==df3)
[1] TRUE
```

You break down (group) the df into parts where each part has the same id and phase, and then you simply number the rows in each of these parts. Note this assumes the df is already sorted chronologically, as in your sample data. If this is not true, you'll have to sort it in advance by `time`.

Comment: Thanks iod! Your solution worked in my earlier example, but unfortunatly my real data was a bit more complex. I've edited my example to represent a sample of my real data. Does group_by in combination with mutate and some editing still work?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what the problem is, or what's the logic of your desired output supposed to be. Can you explain why rows 13 and 14 should be 3, for example? Are you counting phase 2A and 2B as one occurrence?

Comment: Unfortunately the data are not as logical/clean as they should be. Row 13:16 should have occurence "3", because it is the third time the proces starts for id "3" -> fase goes from "finished" to "fase 2B". My occurrence consists of all the rows in between is.na(old_fase) & new_fase != "Finished" | old_fase == "Finished" & new_fase != "Finished". In other words: the occurrence of a proces  cycle within an id.